# C Chomp questions?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create the game Chomp. I am halfway through but pretty stuck.

The game will have 5 different functions. Pointers and structs are not allowed.

This is how far I have come and I have been struggeling with a few problems for a while, but I can't figure out how to solve them by myself so I thought I could get some help here.

**BUGS**

**a)** If you first input **2 2** and then input **2 1** it will say that the position already has been eaten, even though it's a perfectly valid position to eat. Instead of checking if the position is **!= 'O'** I should check if it is **== 'O'**, but that won't work either because in the **check_move()** loop the row and col will not always be an **O**...

**b)** If you input a position that is not inside the matrix (i.e. **20 20**) you will get **two** lines of errors. I don't understand why. Of course I only want to display one error, not two.

**c)** If you input a position that has already been eaten you will get the error "**Already been eaten!**" several times due to the loop that is looping through the print several times.

**QUESTION**

**a)** What is the best way to alternate between **Player 1** and **Player 2**? I thought about an int that will increase by **+1** every time a player makes a valid move. Then I will check if the value of the int is odd or even. Odd = Player 1 and even = Player 2 or vice verca. But that won't work because I'm not allowed to have any more global variables than I currently has. And I'm only allowed to return one value from one function (**check_move()**).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int height    =  4;
int width     = 10;
char matrix[4][10];


void initialize()
{
    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
            matrix[row][col] = 'O';         
}



void print_board()
{
    printf("\n\n");

    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            printf("%c", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    printf("\n\n");
}



void get_move(int player, int input[])
{
    printf("Player %d, make your move: ", player);
    scanf("%d %d", &input[0], &input[1]);
}



int check_move(int position[])
{
    int row     = position[0];
    int col     = position[1];
    int status  =           1;

    if(row <= height  &&  col <= width)
    {
        for(row; row <= height; row++)
        {
            for(col; col <= width; col++)
            {
                // Checks if position already has been eaten
                if(matrix[row-1][col-1] != 'O')
                {
                    printf("Already eaten!\n");
                    status = 0; 
                }

            }
        }       
    }


    else if(row >= height  ||  col >= width)
    {
        printf("Your move must be inside the matrix!\n");
        status = 0;
    }

    return status;
}



void update_board(int x, int y)
{

    for(int xi = x; xi <= 10; ++xi)
    {
        for(int yi = y; yi <= 10; ++yi)
            matrix[xi-1][yi-1] = ' ';       
    }

}



int main(void)
{

    int player = 1;
    int position[2]; 

    initialize();
    print_board();

    while(1){

        get_move(player, position);

        check_move(position);


        while(check_move(position) != 1)
        {
            printf("Try again!\n\n");        
            get_move(player, position);
        }

        update_board(position[0], position[1]);

        print_board();

    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bug a and c:**

Your `check_move` function is wrong, you should only test if the position played is eaten or not, the status of the  other positions are not relevant:

```
int check_move(int pos[])
{
    if(pos[0] < 1 || pos[0] > height  ||  pos[1] < 1 || pos[1] > width)
    {
        printf("Your move must be inside the matrix!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(matrix[ pos[0] - 1 ][ pos[1] - 1 ] != 'O' ) {
        printf("Already eaten!\n");
        return 0; 
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**Bug b:**

You get the error message twice because you're calling `check_move` twice in your main:

```
check_move(position);
while(check_move(position) != 1)
```

Just remove the useless first call to `check_move()`.

**Question a:**

You can switch between players by updating the variable `player` inside your main :

```
player = (player + 1) % maxNumberOfPlayer;
```

This will go from `0` to `maxNumberOfPlayer - 1`, so you may use `printf("Player %d, make your move: ", player + 1);` for a more user-friendly output. Also, if `maxNumberOfPlayer = 2`, `player = (player + 1) % 2;` is equivalent to `player = !player`.

Comment: Thanks! I can't get the player number to work tho. It always stays on 0. `main` contains `int player = 1;` and `player = (player + 1) % 2`. `get_move()` contains `printf("Player %d, make your move: ", player + 1);`

Comment: @user2952320 You should initialize it to `0` not `1` and only outside the loop. And if you indeed print `player + 1`, I can't see how it could print `0`.

Comment: I initialized it to 0 and it's only printing Player 2 all the time.

Comment: I initialized it to 0 and it's only printing Player 2 all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, inside your while loop just add:

```
player = !player;
```

Which will toggle `player` between 0 and 1.